Need to create a foreach loop for a CSV file, using 2 variables, in Powershell
I am new to coding and most of my experience is with Python.
I am working on a simple powershell script that runs a Test-NetConnection on IP address and ports in a CSV file.



IP
Port




1.1.1.1
22


1.1.1.2
25


1.1.1.3
80


1.1.1.4




Each IP needs to be tested with each Port
What I have so far is this, not sure if I need to create a new list with each IP/Port combination, and then run a foreach on them:
$csv_path = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter file path"

$csv = Import-Csv -Path "$csv_path"

foreach($item in $csv){
    "{0} = {1}" -f $item.IP,$item.Port
    Test-NetConnection -ComputerName "$item.IP" -Port "$item.Port" -InformationLevel Detailed
}


"$item.IP" should probably be "$($item.IP)" Same for `"$item.Port"

If you rename the IP column to ComputerName you could just do something like Import-Csv path\to.csv | Test-NetConnection. Aside, remove the double-quotes -> "$item.IP" should be $item.IP

PowerShell has a handy feature called Member-Access Enumeration that you can use here.
In short, if you access a property or method on an array object (for example your $csv variable) it will invoke that property or method on all items in the array and return a new array with the all results in it.
For example with this test data:
PS> $csv = @"
IP,      Port
1.1.1.1, 22
1.1.1.2, 25
1.1.1.3, 80
1.1.1.4,
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

if you invoke $csv.IP you get an array of all the IP properties:
PS> $csv.IP
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.2
1.1.1.3
1.1.1.4

and the same for $csv.Port:
PS> $csv.Port
22
25
80

(note that the "Port" output has 4 items in it - there's a non-printing $null in the fourth index)
We can use this to do a nested loop over all the combinations of IP and Port like this:
# use member-access enumeration to get ip and port arrays,
# and filter out $null or empty string values
$ips   = $csv.IP | where-object { $_ }
$ports = $csv.Port | where-object { $_ }

foreach( $ip in $ips )
{
    foreach( $port in $ports )
    {

        "{0} = {1}" -f $ip, $port
        Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $ip -Port $port -InformationLevel Detailed

    }
}


Is this smart enough to exclude the empty port values? That was why I did it the long way, but if I don't need to that's nice to know.

@JoelCoehoorn Actually, no, it doesn’t. It just looks like it on screen because it doesn’t render any output for the $null at the end of ports…

ok, fixed - thanks for the prompt :-)

This is the one. This is exactly what I had in mind I just didn't know how to manifest it. Just tested it and ran it, and it works. And it does not break if the IP's and Port's increase.
Thank you!


Each IP needs to be tested with each Port

So you're checking ports 22,25, and 80 for all four IPs? 12 checks in total based on the sample data?
That's not how csv data is supposed to work, but okay, we can still do that.
$csv_path = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter file path"

$csv = Import-Csv -Path $csv_path

foreach($itemIP in $csv | ?{$_.IP.Length -gt 0}) {
    foreach($itemPort in $csv | ?{$_.Port.Length -gt 0}) {
        "$($itemIP.IP) = $($itemPort.Port)"
        Test-NetConnection -ComputerName "$($itemIP.IP)" -Port "$($itemPort.Port)" -InformationLevel Detailed
    }
}


If you have 1 IP and 1 Port per CSV row, a way to simplify your code can be to rename the IP column to ComputerName:



ComputerName
Port




1.1.1.1
22


1.1.1.2
25


1.1.1.3
80



Then, because both parameters (-ComputerName and -Port) take pipeline input by Property Name, you can pipe the output from Import-Csv directly to Test-NetConnection:
$csv_path = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter file path"
Import-Csv -Path $csv_path | Test-NetConnection -InformationLevel Detailed

The other option, if you want to have multiple ports per row with a delimiter, i.e.: a semi-colon:



IP
Port




1.1.1.1
22; 80


1.1.1.2
25; 444


1.1.1.3
80



You could split by semi-colon on the .Port property and the use the same logic as above, create one object per port with properties that can be bound from pipeline:
Import-Csv -Path $csv_path | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($port in $_.Port -split '\s*;\s*') {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            ComputerName = $_.IP
            Port         = $port
        }
    }
} | Test-NetConnection -InformationLevel Detailed


Using this (multipurpose) JoinModule (see also: https://github.com/iRon7/Join-Object):
# "Import-Csv -Path $csv_path"
# Using your question data for a full Minimal, Reproducible Example:
Install-Script -Name Read-HtmlTable
$Data = Read-HtmlTable https://stackoverflow.com/q/78822669/1701026 -Table 0

Install-Module -Name JoinModule

$Data.Ip | CrossJoin $Data.Port | ForEach-Object { "{0} = {1}" -f @($_) }
1.1.1.1 = 22
1.1.1.1 = 25
1.1.1.1 = 80
1.1.1.1 =
1.1.1.2 = 22
1.1.1.2 = 25
1.1.1.2 = 80
1.1.1.2 =
1.1.1.3 = 22
1.1.1.3 = 25
1.1.1.3 = 80
1.1.1.3 =
1.1.1.4 = 22
1.1.1.4 = 25
1.1.1.4 = 80
1.1.1.4 =

In case you want to skip the empty Port:
$Ports = $Data.Port | Where-Object { $_ }
$Data.Ip | CrossJoin $Ports | ForEach-Object { "{0} = {1}" -f @($_) }
1.1.1.1 = 22
1.1.1.1 = 25
1.1.1.1 = 80
1.1.1.2 = 22
1.1.1.2 = 25
1.1.1.2 = 80
1.1.1.3 = 22
1.1.1.3 = 25
1.1.1.3 = 80
1.1.1.4 = 22
1.1.1.4 = 25
1.1.1.4 = 80

